# Spectral theory of differential forms over a circle bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, principal-bundles, laplacian

Here is the set up : I consider the unitary tangent bundle of a surface $(S,g)$ endowed with the Sasakian metric ; $(T^1S, g_s)$, in fact we have the following fibration :
\begin{equation*}
  \mathbb{S}^1 \to T^1 S \underset{p}{\to} S
\end{equation*}
where $p$ is Riemannian submersion. We also have a natural action, the rotation in the fiber, which give a structure of $\mathbb{S}^1$-principal bundle.

I am interested in the eigen one-form of the Laplacian associated to the Sasakian metric, differential forms defined on $T^1S$ verifying $\Delta \omega = \lambda \omega$, with $\Delta$ the Hodge laplacian. My question is :

Given all the eigenfunctions and eingenforms, let say $\eta$, associated to the Hodge Laplacian on the basis (and there pull back in $T^1S$ ,$p^*(\eta)$ ) and all the $\mathbb{S}^1$-invariant function (like the euler class for instance) does it possible to give a kind of formula which gives all the eingenforms of the Hodge Laplacian for the Sasakian metric ?

Any references would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you don't get a principal $S^1$-bundle unless you pick an orientation. In particular I think the unit tangent bundle of a nonorientable surface is not principal. (The problem is that without an orientation you can't consistently decide which direction to rotate the fiber.)

Comment: Yes you right, I forgot to ask the surface to be oriented...